finding web elements in selenium java
I am very new to Selenium and Programming. I am unable to find the textbox elements.
This is my code.
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Admin");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("admin123");

These 2 are html textboxes:
<input data-v-1f99f73c="" class="oxd-input oxd-input--active" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus="">
<input data-v-1f99f73c="" class="oxd-input oxd-input--active" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">

I am getting error like no such elements found.

You haven't included the HTML that shows they should be findable this way.

Your locators look fine. Have you checked if the targeted elements are within an IFRAME. If there is no IFRAME present, then try using selenium's waits. Can you share the URL of the website if it is public?

https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login This is the website I am using. I don't see any IFRAME here.

Those inputs are created via JavaScript and your code needs to wait until this has happened.

Try this:
driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/web/index.php/auth/login");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("username"))).sendKeys("Admin");   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("password"))).sendKeys("admin123");

Imports required:
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import java.time.Duration;

